# How can I trap Cntl-C while using Perl's Term::ShellUI?

Tags: perl, terminal

I used [Term::ShellUI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ShellUI) and almost every thing 
is working as expected but the issue is when I pressed Ctrl-C I want to 
print:

> Please use ctrl+d to exit the shell

For that I handle the signal but the message print only after I pressed the new line 
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same without using the IO::Handle library, by setting the $| variable to 1 before printing.

```
$SIG{INT} = sub {
   $| = 1;
   print "Please use ctrl+d to exit the shell";
}
```

Comment: This does not work. See http://mail.pm.org/pipermail/melbourne-pm/2007-January/002214.html for the real answer